# modify Laravel Auth registration page

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I am trying to modify the Laravel Auth registration system in that I'd like to require that a token parameter be provided in order for the user to be able to access the registration page (ie http://website.dev/register/{tokenhere}). Below is the pertinent code:

From my routes\web.php file:

```
Route::get('/register/{token}', function() {
    //
})->middleware('token');
```

From my \App\Http\Middleware\CheckToken.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckToken
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->token != 'test') { #just hard coding something here for testing purposes
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I also added `'token' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckToken::class` to the $routeMiddleware array in \App\Http\Kernel.php

However, I go to http://website.dev/register and I'm able to access the page, despite not providing a token parameter. I can also see that if I provide the 'test' parameter that the middleware is looking for (http://website.dev/register/test), I get a blank page.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I'm quite new to MVC and Laravel. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create custom route, like /register/{token} and handle this token in the controller. Maybe even set in middleware group if you want.

Comment: thanks. however, i still seem to be doing something wrong as it's still not working (see edited post).

Comment: I think you don't need to use middleware there. Just write route something like `Route::get('/register/{token}', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');` and after in RegisterController write function  `public function register($token)` and there you can handle the token how you want.